# The content type of return string of PHP function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a PHP function in laravel framework which accept post request and return a json, however I checked the response content type of the returned json. It is in text/html.

I want to make it in text/plain, I set

```
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

In the beginning of PHP file. Just like follows:

```
 <?php

  header("Content-Type: text/plain");

 public function binResize() {
    if(Input::has('file_link') && Input::has('width') && Input::has('format') ) {


        $url = Input::get('file_link'); 
        $url = urldecode($url);
        $filename = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);          

        return json_encode(array('the_file'->$url);

    }
}
>
```

But it still returns (in text/html). So any other setting that I need to set? Like in

```
PHP.INI /Apache config/ or index.php
```

Comment: I checked the php.ini file, the default_mimetype = "text/html"
However, I want to override it in PHP file. Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

return json_encode(array('the_file'->$url);
```

you can use

```
return Response::json(array('the_file'->$url), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'));
```